# infinite loop detected when the page is refreshed on angular 2 along with dot net core 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core

I have a `dotnet core 2.0` and `angular 2` app that allows me to see member details. First I have a list page that displays all the members from sql server database. Then each member has a link to take me to see the details individually. I have a `member.service.ts` is providing the service. The issue is that when I refresh the `details-member.component.html` page, the server is keep spinning and returns no value. Only error that I have is `"firstName" is not defined`. However, without the refresh, everything is working.

**member.service.ts**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MemberService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getAllMembers(){
    return this.http.get('/api/members').map(res => res.json());
}

getMember(id:any){
    return this.http.get("/api/members/" + id).map(res => res.json());
}
}
```

**details-member.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MemberService } from '../../../services/member.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-details-member',
   templateUrl: 'details-member.component.html'
})

export class DetailsMemberComponent implements OnInit {
   member: any;
   memberId:number;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private memberService: MemberService,
) { 
    route.params.subscribe(p => {
        this.memberId = +p['id'];
        if (isNaN(this.memberId) || this.memberId <= 0) {
          router.navigate(['/member/list-members']);
          return; 
        }
      });
}

ngOnInit() { 
    this.memberService.getMember(this.memberId)
    .subscribe(
      v => this.member = v,
      err => {
        if (err.status == 404) {
          this.router.navigate(['/members/list-members']);
          return; 
        }
      });
    }
}
```

**details-member.component.html**

```
<div class="page-header clearfix detailHeading">
    <h1 class="text-muted">Demographic Details</h1>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>Full Name : <b>{{ member.firstName }} {{ member.middleName }} 
{{ member.lastName }}</b></p>
        <p>Gender : <b>{{ member.gender }}</b></p>
        <p>Date of Brith : <b>{{ member.dateOfBirth | date }}</b></p>
        <p>Age : <b>{{ member.dateOfBirth | age }}</b></p>
        <p>Race : <b>{{ member.race }}</b></p>
        <p>Education : <b>{{ member.education }}</b></p>
        <p>Address : <b>{{ member.address }}</b></p>
        <p>Emergency Contact Name : <b></b></p>
        <p>Emergency Contact Address : <b></b></p>
        <p>Emergency Contact Phone : <b></b></p>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <hr>
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                Created : <b>{{ member.createdDate | date:'medium' }} by {{ member.createdBy }}</b>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                Last Update : <b>{{ member.updatedDate | date:'medium' }} by {{ member.updatedBy }}</b>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

The exact error I receieve is :`fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore,NodeServices[0] ERROR TypeError: Cannot read propery 'firstName' of undefined`. 
Again the issue happens only when the details page is refreshed.

Comment: put your use route.params.subscribe in your function ngOnInit, not in the constructor, and the this.memberService.getMember(this.memberId) in the subscribe of the route.params.subscribe

Comment: Nope! I got the same problem.

Comment: the problem is that the service don't give you the data of the member (because this.memberId have no value? because fall the data?. Try to write console.log(this.memberId) and console.log(v) to check what it's happened. Tip you can use in your html member?.firstname, member?.gender, etc.. (the ?. want say: If member is defined, show me the property, if not, show me nothing

Comment: I have removed route.params.subscribe int to the ngOnInint as you wrote above. I also followed your second comment as well. Still, it causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what caused this problem but I fixed by changing (adding `x` in front of `asp-prerender-module`) the following tag inside the `index.cshtml` file.

```
<app xasp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Application is Loading...</app>
```